# How do I view the database that EntityFramework created for me?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

Just starting off with MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5 (4.4 for .net 4). I've defined a couple models and saved something to database. I want to see what's going on behind the scenes, but I can't figure out how to connect to this database. How do I do it?

I assume I can connect to it [via the Server Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqCRk.png) somehow, but I'm not sure what options to pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the connection string using DbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString - it will tell you everything since it is used to connect to the database. Then in server explorer you should know whether to pick SqlExpress or one of the SqlCompact options.

Comment: I get "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MvcApplication1.Models.BlogContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE", but I don't see "SQL Express" as a Data Source. Which one should I pick?

Comment: Pick "Microsoft Sql Server" On the next wizard page in the "Server name" textbox put ".\SqlExpress" and from the "Select or enter database name" drop down select "MvcApplication1.Models.BlogContext" and press OK. The connection you added should show up in the Server Explorer in Data Connections and you should be able to drill into to it and see tables etc.

Comment: Thank you for spelling this out for me. Wasn't obvious to me. "MARK-PC" was the only server popping up when I clicked the dropdown; I thought that was all that was available.

Comment: . is a shorthand for the localhost. If your machine is called MARK-PC you should be able to use both .\SqlExpress and MARK-PC\SqlExpress. If you try opening the drop down it will search for all Sql servers in your network. On a single machine you can have multiple instances of the Sql Server. I think that by default for non-SqlExpress editions (e.g. Standard edition) there is no named instance (so you use only the name of the machine) but SqlExpress usually installs as SqlExpress instance so you need to use .\SqlExpress (or {MachineName}\SqlExpress)